# myTagOverflow - StackOverflow top tags data visualization

Tags: app, tags, statistics

#### About

myTagOverflow creates a visualization of the top tags related to your own activity on stackOverflow.

It may be useful when you want to demonstrate your technical abilities, based on factual data ;).

How it works:

- Connect your stackExchange account
- Visualize statistics about the tags you interact the most with on stackExchange
- Adjust the graph layout by dragging/dropping tags
- Use the visualization in your own website, CV or share on social media...

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Download / Install

[Access to myTagOverflow online](https://mango-is.com/tools/myTagOverflow/?utm_source=stackOverflow&utm_medium=stackapps-post&utm_campaign=myTagOverflow-beta-release).

#### Platform

myTagOverflow is a web application.

#### Contact

Created by Mehdi El Fadil.
You may get in touch via [github issues](https://github.com/Mango-information-systems/mango-is-website/labels/myTagOverflow).

#### License

Dual Licensed MIT / Apache.

myTagOverflow is free and open source. Contact us if there is any question.

#### Code

Following technologies are used:

- d3.js
- javascript / ejs
- HTML / CSS
- node.js / browserify / uglifyjs

Contributions welcome, [let's discuss](https://github.com/Mango-information-systems/mango-is-website/labels/myTagOverflow) :)